# Write variable into same javascript file

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I have

```
var world = 'here are positions of the blocks and character Mario';
```

I want change "Mario" to another character (for example, "Luigi").

```
var res = world.replace("Mario", "Luigi");
```

Now I need to write the code (res) with world and changed character into this file to be loaded by engine.

```
    window._world = {
  id: 3,
  tiles: [],
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  tileWidth: 32,
  tileHeight: 32,
  width: 212,
  height: 17,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(66, 66, 255, 1)",
  name: "level_1-1",
  sprites: [

**Here I need write the variable res with changed character**

 ],
```

How can I do this?

Comment: write how/where? on the JS file on the server that gets served up? you do NOT want joe random client rewriting files on your server. why can't you just have JS code on the clien to mod the string however you want?

Comment: Yeah I could have the map blocks in the sprites as I needed, but how can I search sprites [ content ] for mario and replace with luigi? I don't know how I know only how to do that if it's in variable.

Comment: Improve spelling and syntax

Answer (score 0):

I thought your expecting this thing:

```
var world = 'here are positions of the blocks and character mario';
var res = world.replace("mario", "luigi");
window._world = {
   id: 3,
   tiles: [],
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
  tileWidth: 32,
  tileHeight: 32,
  width: 212,
  height: 17,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(66, 66, 255, 1)",
  name: "level_1-1",
 sprites: [res]
}

console.log(window._world)
```

Comment: I've try this, but I get error: TypeError: Backbone[cls] is not a constructor

Comment: Or it can be in the sprites:[ ] but I need searched the sprites for mario and replace with luigi, is that possible?

Comment: window._world.sprites[0] = window._world.sprites[0].replace('mario', 'luigi');

Comment: It says "TypeError: window._world.sprites[0].replace is not a function"